# Icefaces JSFgo to bottom of page?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jsf-1.2, icefaces-1.8

I have multiple rows on a table and when i click on a button (ice:command Link) from one row i want to scroll to bottom of page. 
I tried to use a java script function on the on click event but the issue is that after the scroll go's down it comes right back to the button clicked.

```
function onclickToBottom()
{
     window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
```

Is there a way to prevent that like an javascript event that would run after all icefaces javascript done executing ?? thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have an action listener for your `ice:commandLink`?. May be that's why you are experiencing such a behavior.

There are two options you can try.

1. Use `addJavascriptCall` method of `com.icesoft.faces.context.effects.JavascriptContext` to call your script within the actionListener. This means, you shouldn't have an onclick script in your link.
2. Use HTML anchor tag `<a>` instead of `<ice:commandLink>` and add your script call to onclick event. You can just style it using ICEfaces style classes.